# Batch seperate by colon and return result in one line

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way to properly seperate the line by using colon, and then make a new line with both of the results. its basically email adresses, and password documents.

I have a full file of lines with something like this:

```
wellctsited@live.fr:tJL2EjWA
```

I'm trying to make it to output result to a new file ( adding a line, to be the following):

```
insert into test wellctsited@live.fr pw tJL2EjWA
```

how can I accomplish this?

I found out that I can seperate it by using something like:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%LINE") do (
```

but then it would get me the password, and not holding username?

Current code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  ( accs.txt) do  (
    ECHO Processing %%A.... 

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%A") do (
        ECHO THIS IS TRUE: %%b
    )
    @echo insert into test %%A pw  %%b
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change the wildcard to 1-2 and add delims to your pull.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in (C:\Temp\TestBatch.txt) do (
   REM If you want the "Processing" to show the original input, do %%a:%%b
   ECHO Processing %%a.... 
   @echo insert into test %%a pw %%b
)
pause
```

Wildcard code result:

```
Processing wellctsited@live.fr:tJL2EjWA....
THIS IS TRUE: tJL2EjWA
insert into test wellctsited@live.fr:tJL2EjWA pw  %b
```

1-2 code result:

```
Processing wellctsited@live.fr....
insert into test wellctsited@live.fr pw tJL2EjWA
```

Comment: how i gather the email then when %%b only shows the pw?

Comment: Modified it for you.

Comment: In case there could be a colon in the password I'd use `"tokens=1* delims=:"`